# ExtJS 4 - How to remove the effect from the labels of disabled fields and display them in same way as other fields?

Tags: css, extjs, label, textfield

I have a form in ExtJS where I want to show some textfiedls as 'disabled'.

For this, I am using disabled:true config property. But due to this the font style of label is getting changed which is not wanted.

I need to display the labels of disabled fields same as the other fields.

After going through dom, I found that for disabled fields, the class which is getting applied is - x-item-disabled, but I am not being able to make it same as others.

Could anyone suggest a way for it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been able to find a solution for this as following:

```
.x-item-disabled .x-form-item-label,
.x-item-disabled .x-form-cb-label {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=90);
    opacity: 0.9; 
}
```

The above class can be added to the project's custom css. I have tested it against ExtJs version 4.1 and found it to be working perfectly.

Hope this helps someone looking for the same.

Answer (score 3):

set the 'disabledCls' config option in your form field setup.

Config Example

```
{
  fieldLabel: 'First Name',
  name: 'first',
  allowBlank:false,
  disabled:true,
  xtype: 'textfield',
  disabledCls: 'myDisabledClass'
}
```

CSS

```
.myDisabledClass input{
    opacity: .3;
    -moz-opacity: .3;
    filter: alpha(opacity=30);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Williams, it works great! Just that in IE9 unfortunately I am not able to see its effect, though in Mozilla its perfect. Does opacity has some issue in IE?

Comment: Great William, thanks for sharing again. I used this one, and the appearance in IE9 improved, but is still different from the one in Mozilla. I wanted to upload the images here for both but couldn't find an option to do so while placing a comment. I tried playing around with opcaity feature and test if something changed but no luck.

Comment: Try using .6 and 60 respectively for the values. Those are the default extjs values.

Comment: You can add the images to your question as well.

Comment: Sorry for a late reply. But this unfortunately is not working in IE. I compared the div generated for disabled fields in IE and FF and found that IE has disabled='' added to the top div. If in the DOM I take this disabled='' off then the label of such a field becomes same as others in IE too. Is there anyway this disabled property of div can be accessed and removed dynamically from the div in IE? Thanks for your time so far.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing but I found my way using simply the attribute `fieldStyle` in my `textfield` ExtJS object like this:

```
{  xtype: 'textfield',
   id: 'myTextfield',
   width:"20%",
   **fieldStyle:** 'text-align: right; **opacity: 1;**',
   style: {
     marginLeft: '10px'
   },
   disabled: true
 }
```